# How many codewords with same syndrome and weight

Tags: coding-theory

Suppose a parity check matrix $H$ of a random binary linear code. What is a limit of codewords with same syndrome and weight, such that the Syndrome decoding problem is still NP-Complete? There is some paper about that? Could you help me please?

Comment: What do you mean by "such that the Syndrome decoding problem is still NP-Complete"?  It is the problem as a whole that is NP-complete, not a particular instance.

Comment: _All_ codewords have syndrome $0$, So, your question boils down to "How many codewords have weight $w$ for a specified value for $w$?" The answer to this is known for _ very few_ codes only, and is unknown "almost surely" for a random code.